# having trouble with the length function in r

Tags: r, sum

```
Miner = function(n)
{
  x = sample(c(2,3,5), 1, replace = TRUE, prob = c(1/3,1/3,1/3))
  if (n == 0) {r = 0}
  else if (x == 2) {r = c(2, Miner(n - 1))}
  else if (x == 3) {r = c(3, Miner(n))}
  else if (x == 5) {r = c(5, Miner(n))}
  return(sum(r))
}
```

Instead of returning `sum(r)`, i need to return `sum(r)` divided by the number of times that the number 2 appears in `r`.

I have tried everything from `length(r[r == 2])` to `sum(r == 2)` to `sum(nchar(r[r == 2]))` but nothing seems to work. Would greatly appreciate some help.

Comment: This is a classic recursion misunderstanding. If you place a `print(r)` right before your return statement, you will see that with each iteration, `r` isn't the vector you are expecting.  If you simply return `r` instead of `sum(r)`, your return value is a vector and you are probably expecting that you can simply operate on this final output. Well, with recursion, each iteration is performing the return operation.

Comment: To fix your problem, simply return `r`, then call `temp <- Miner(n)` and your solution is `sum(temp)/(sum(temp == 2))`

Comment: Much appreciated, this worked. Hopefully I'm allowed to do that. It's a school assignment so the prof may want everything in the body of the main function. I definitely need to think about whats going on after taking your suggestion to put print(r) in the code. Not making too much sense atm. Thanks again:)